# Discrepancy between sorting of coordinate points across major browsers using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser, coordinates

In a web application I'm developing I am detecting the boundary of certain images and generating an array of coordinate points along the detected boundaries.  Because of how the array is generated the coordinate points are not guaranteed to be in any particular order.  I wrote a comparer function that calculates the cross products of the vector for any two given points from a center point to determine relative position.  This is working fine in chrome, however in both firefox 21.0 and IE 10 some of the coordinate points are not sorted properly.

The code of the comparer function and the sorting function are as follows:

```
function sortCounterClockwise(a, b) {
    return ((isALeftOfB(a, b)) ? 1 : -1);
    //return ((isALeftOfB(a, b)) ? 1 : ((isALeftOfB(b, a)) ? -1 : 0));
}

function isALeftOfB(a, b) {
    var det = (a.x - center.x) * (b.y - center.y) - (b.x - center.x) * (a.y - center.y);
    if (det < 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (det > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    var d1 = (a.x - center.x) * (a.x - center.x) + (a.y - center.y) * (a.y - center.y);
    var d2 = (b.x - center.x) * (b.x - center.x) + (b.y - center.y) * (b.y - center.y);
    return d1 < d2;
}
```

I have created a complete working jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Zsz3K/1/ where if you view it in Chrome you will see the proper, if crude outline of the state of Montana, but in FF and IE it will have mixed up coordinate points.

I have tried numerous variations of the above algorithm, but I cannot get it to work in all my test cases in FF or IE, only chrome.  In a previous iteration I held one point fixed as a reference point, thinking that IE and FF were getting tripped up by the cyclical nature of the sorting. My test case is uploading a map of the US, and chrome is able to successfully detect and trace all borders correctly.  I can't change the program to guarantee that the coordinate array is sorted by increasing or decreasing theta from the center point, and really need to find a consistent way to sort these coordinates that works correctly in the browsers listed here.  As far as I can tell, this seems like a bug in FF and IE, given that the results are based on mathematical results that should be immutable across browsers.

Edit:  Moved my answer to an answer.

Comment: Going back to the first version of your fiddle, it seems to be working. What's wrong with http://jsfiddle.net/Zsz3K/ ?

Comment: @Jake when I first made the fiddle I added the points in such a way that it worked.  The updated fiddle changed the order of the points, which caused it to stop working in FF and IE.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an update to the jsfiddle that I suppose answers my own question, vaguely.  http://jsfiddle.net/Zsz3K/3/

I roughed out a quick bubble sort and added in an additional condition on the comparer function about relative placement in respect to the center point, and it works in all 3 browsers.  I guess that the take away is that the .sort() implementation in FF and IE just doesn't seem to work well with this sort of data.  I wish I had the time to dive into the jquery guts, but I don't.  So in the unlikely event that someone else runs across the problem of sorting spatial coordinates in jquery, don't rely on the built in sort functions, though I would recommend something more efficient than a vanilla bubble sort as anything other than a proof of concept.  Strangely enough chrome not only consistently worked using the built in .sort() with the comparer, but it didn't need (and in fact was tripped up by) the use of relative position to the center as a sorting criteria.

And just to satisfy the code requirement for linking to jsfiddle, here is the working sort and comparer.

```
do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i=0; i < points.length-1; i++) {
        if (isALeftOfB(points[i + 1], points[i])) {
            var temp = points[i];
            points[i] = points[i+1];
            points[i+1] = temp;
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
} while (swapped);

function isALeftOfB(a, b) {
if (a.y <= center.y && b.y > center.y) {
        return true;
    } else if (a.y == center.y && b.y == center.y) {
        return a.x < b.x
    }
    var det = (a.x - center.x) * (b.y - center.y) - (b.x - center.x) * (a.y - center.y);
    if (det < 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (det > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    var d1 = (a.x - center.x) * (a.x - center.x) + (a.y - center.y) * (a.y - center.y);
    var d2 = (b.x - center.x) * (b.x - center.x) + (b.y - center.y) * (b.y - center.y);
    return d1 < d2;
}
```